# UV Mapping a sculpted object shows glitches

Tags: texturing, uv, sculpting

I am going through some fundamentals in UV mapping and I am taking my first steps in UV mapping a sculpted object. The way I created the object (representing a candle) was:

- taking a cylinder
- apply a mirror modifier
- apply 3 subdivision modifiers to obtain more dense and detailed geometry to have more details for the sculpting part
- and then started sculpting.

  Problem is that now I just added the plain checkers UV and I see these weird stuff happening for the first time. The candle in the Scene Collection is:

[image]

The weird stuff happening is:

[image]

Any idea of what is going wrong?

The way it should be from the tutorial I am following:

[image]`

EDIT:

after cutting the object in half with a Seam and re-unwrapping the glitches are still there (see image below) plus you can see the weird behavior I recorded in this video:

https://youtu.be/bpuPxHHol1U

[image]

Comment: It's showing you the original UV map from the object.  You need to reunwrap it with your altered geometry to get a UV more similar to your tutorial.  You'll also need to seam it appropriately.

Comment: @Nathan tried to do as you say but unfortunately it doesn't work. Check out the EDIT in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by:

- Go to sculpt mode
- Re-mesh the object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- *Add* and *Apply* a [Subdivision Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) to increase topology definition again
- Shade Smooth
- Smart UV unwrap

Answer (score 1):

Don't apply the subdivision modifier. This makes the geometry unnecessarily dense. Re-meshing may have solved your problem but this will not hold up.

Also smart UV unwrap isn't the best way to unwrap because of lack of control. Instead make creases and then unwrap using <kbd>U</kbd>*>Unwrap>Unwrap*. Also learn about edge-flow. This is very important when modelling.